# nested mongoose models in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

how to injected mongoose model in other mongoose schema..
when I try this :

```
@Schema()
export class Party {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Player.name) private _player: mongoose.Model<Player>,
  ) {}
  get player() {
    return this._player;
  }

  @Prop({ required: true })
name:string;
}
```

in player modeul:

```
  @Injectable()
    @Schema()
    export class Player {
      @Prop({ required: true })
      player_name: string;
      @Prop({ default: '' })
      email: string;}
```

it give undefined as a result for party getter

the app module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
  ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env', 
      isGlobal: true,
    }),

    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DATABASE_URL),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Player.name, schema: PlayerSchema },
      { name: Party.name, schema: PartySchema },
    ]),
  ],
 
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Is there a way to make this work?